# Bug Scrolling Modal Bootstrap Append Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, css3, modal

Olá pessoal estou com um BUG de CSS, muito provavelmente, no scroll do meu modal bootstrap. Eu tenho uma busca ajax que retorna alguns resultados e eu estou usando o append do jquery para preencher o modal com os resultados retornados. Só que o scroll não está ativando mesmo tendo a classe de modal para rolagem. Vou deixar aqui o código do modal e código da consulta ajax.

Código Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="pullBankSlips" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="loadingContentModal p-5 m-5 d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-header d-none">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5">Enviar Boletos</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('bankSlips.upload') }}"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body d-none">
                <div id="bankSlipsContent"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-none">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código consulta ajax:

```
function sendSelectedBankSlips() {
        var selectedBankSlips = $('#bankSlipsTable input[name=check]:checked');

        $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").html('');
        $("#pullBankSlips .modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer").addClass('d-none');
        $(".loadingContentModal").removeClass('d-none');
        $("#pullBankSlips").modal('show');

        var countBankSlips = selectedBankSlips.length;
        var count = 0;

        $(selectedBankSlips).each(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ route('bankSlips.pull') }}",
                data: {
                    id: this.value
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    count = count + 1;
                          
                    if(count == countBankSlips){
                        $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append('<input type="hidden" name="bankSlips[]" value="'+data[0].id+'"><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cliente:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="'+data[1].name+'" type="text" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">E-mail:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input value="'+data[2].value+'" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailClients[]"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Boleto:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="'+data[0].original_name+'" type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="d-flex mt-1 justify-content-end"><a href="{{ env("APP_URL") }}/storage/'+data[0].file_path+'" target="_blank">Visualizar Boleto</a></div></div>');
                        $(".loadingContentModal").addClass('d-none');

                        $("#pullBankSlips .modal-header, .modal-body, .modal-footer").removeClass('d-none');
                        
                    }else{
                        $("#pullBankSlips #bankSlipsContent").append('<input type="hidden" name="bankSlips[]" value="'+data[0].id+'"><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cliente:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="'+data[1].name+'" type="text" class="form-control"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">E-mail:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input value="'+data[2].value+'" type="email" class="form-control" name="emailClients[]"></div></div><div class="row mb-3"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Boleto:</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input readonly value="'+data[0].original_name+'" type="text" class="form-control"></div><div class="d-flex mt-1 justify-content-end"><a href="{{ env("APP_URL") }}/storage/'+data[0].file_path+'" target="_blank">Visualizar Boleto</a></div></div><hr/>');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

[image: imagem do bug]